# Anyway to calibrate printed page scaling in Windows?

Tags: printing, label

We're printing on small Avery labels (half inch height), #5267, via an ancient version of Bartender. We've noticed that the label content is drifting up the label by a little under 1/16 by the time it gets to the bottom of the label.

Subsequently, I've done tested with this PDF ruler:

http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/paper_rulers/UnstableURL/ruler_foot.pdf

All via Chrome's PDF renderer from the same computer to a variety of printers:

An old HP6, two models of large Ricoh workgroup printers, two Brother HL-5370DW's, and an Brother HL-2030.

The majority are printing the same PDF slightly short. The Ricoh's seem to be the most accurate - they're also the most expensive machines of the bunch.

I would like to set a scaling/calibration factor somewhere to work around this. Is there such a thing hiding in Windows?

UPDATE: I gave up and hacked up the BarTender label design... I made the labels 0.51 tall instead of 0.50 inches and adjusted the bottom margin to make it all balance out to 11 inches page length. I'm not super happy with it, but it will do - until the printer is changed.

Comment: It sounds like your label template is slightly off.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Your update was where I was headed with my comment.  Consider posting an answer with your solution (and you can accept it to indicate that the problem has been "solved".

Answer (score 0):

I would download what you want to print first.

When you load what you printing in your software (foxit or adobe reade for example) When you Press CTRL + P for printing, go to Preferences.  Most of the options are in there for bleeding or resizing and such.  That is where I would start.

Otherwise you will have to edit the size of what you are printing with a photo editing software (you may have to convert what you are printing to be able to edit it - for example from PDF to JPG).